# Python search for value in string using wildcards

Tags: python, search, python-2.7

I'm trying to make an address book for a school project, but I can't get my head around searching for values when part of the value is queried.

Here is the block of code at which I am stuck on:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
with open("data.csv") as file:
    for rowdata in csv.reader(file):
        row = self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
        if query in rowdata:
            self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
            for column, data in enumerate(rowdata):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data)
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
```

As you can see, I'm using a PyQt TableWidget to display search results from a csv file. The code above does work, but it only displays the result when a full query is given. The line of code that checks for a match is:

```
        if query in rowdata:
```

So for example, if I wanted to find someone called John, I would have to search for exactly "John". It wouldn't appear if I searched "Joh" or "john" or "hn" and so on...

If you require more information, just ask :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you want to do is search for `query` within the fields of your rows, not the whole row at once.

The problem you're having is that `string in obj` does different things depending on what type `obj` has. If it is a string, it does a substring search (like you want). If it is a non-string container however, it does a regular membership check (which is why it only finds exact matches now).

So to fix it, change your test from `if query in rowdata` to `if any(query in field for field in rowdata)`. If you only want to search for matches within a specific field (like the contact's name) then it could be even simpler: `if query in rowdata[name_column]` (where `name_column` is the number of the column of the `name` field is in your CSV file).

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes perfect sense, I guess. Thanks for providing a way of using specific columns as well! An upvote for you sir.